# Изучение Swift мобильная разработка

Tags: swift

Решил выучить Swift (прочитал книгу: Swift. Основы разработки приложений под iOS и macOS - Усов), а вот дальше не знаю что делать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, следующие шаги. Может быть смотреть курсы онлайн или еще что-то? Дорожную карту для изучения Свифта я не нашел.

По синтаксису и по базовым понятиям я уже прошёлся (в институте изучал Си) меня интересует GUI часть как поступится?
Знаю голый Си я пишу только консольные академические программы, не хочу чтобы со свифтом так стало (подойдет ли курс https://swiftbook.ru)?
Как подступиться к данному вопросу?

Comment: Таких вопросов явно бы не возникло, если бы утверждение "Знаю голый Си" соответствовало действительности. Ну а фактически единственная сфера применения языка swift - написание поделий под ios. Покупайте mac, пару iphone, регистриуйте яблочный аккаунт и можете смело штамповать todo list adware приложения для магазина.

Comment: Ответьте себе на вопрос: зачем вам изучать Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftBook хороший курс. Можете дополнительно поспрашивать о нем в телеграм канале с таким же названием.
В любом случае не затягивайте с написанием собственного приложения, тем более, что для написания простого (и не очень) приложения не всегда нужен платный аккаунт разработчика. Можете писать приложения приобретя макбук и устройство, а потом, уже с помощью платного аккаунта разместить его в апсторе (при таком подходе на вас не будут давить заплаченные деньги). Главное, может и не очевидное, не делайте tо-dо листы или калькуляторы или расписания звонков школы, как обычно советуют. Лучше посмотрите вокруг себя, у вас есть какие-то хобби, для которым можно сделать приложение. Плюс здесь в том, что, во первых вы сделаете хорошее приложение, так как хорошо разбираетесь в интересном для вас вопросе, а во вторых, при написании у вас много раз будут моменты, когда вам кажется, что проблему ну никак не получится решить. И возможно вы бы бросили все на пол-пути, но, то что приложение связано с вашими интересами будет мотивировать вас к преодолению проблем.
В общем вот вам карта: купите макбук (или, если с деньгами совсем не гуд, установите хакинтош), купите б/у айфон или айпад (если уже нет своего) для тестирования (хотя и здесь, на первых этапах можно тестировать на симуляторе), оплачивайте курсы свифтбук, пройдите их, можно не все, а только первую половину, так как последние там не нужны для первых ваших творений (хотя и полезны в дальнейшем). И после курсов начинайте писать свое приложение, как я описал выше. Практика наше всё. Но и про теорию потом не забывайте.

Comment: спасибо за ответы